# Unable to access XML nodes using in loop using pugixml

Tags: xml, loops, pugixml

I have an XML file with the following format

```
<Objects>
    <Object>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>Head</Name>
    </object>
    <Object>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>Right Hand</Name>
    </object>
    <Object>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <Name>Left Hand</Name>
    </object>
    <Object>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <Name>Right hand</Name>
    </object>
    <Object>
        <Id>5</Id>
        <Name>Cup</Name>
    </object>
    <Object>
        <Id>6</Id>
        <Name>Book</Name>
    </object>
</Objects>
```

And I want to use a loop to access my file object by object with the following ways:

```
xml_node nodeObjects = doc.child("Objects").child("Object");

    for(xml_node_iterator it = nodeObjects.begin(); it != nodeObjects.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout<<"Name = "<<it->child_value("Name")<<endl;
    }
```

and also:

```
xml_node nodeObjects = doc.child("Objects");
for(xml_node nodeObject = nodeObjects.first_child(); nodeObject; nodeObject = nodeObject.next_sibling())
    {
        numOfObjects += 1;
        const char *id = nodeObject.child_value("Id");
        const char *name = nodeObject.child_value("Name");

        //cout<<"ID = "<<id<<" Name = "<<name<<endl;
        //cout<<nodeObjects.next_sibling("Object").child_value("Id")<<endl;;

    }
```

And finally:

```
xml_node nodeObjects = doc.child("Objects");
for(xml_node nodeObjects: nodeObjects.children("Object"))
    {
    }
```

While the first two methods did not print the expected results (only the first iteration works), the compiler says that third method is a syntax error!

Any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your XML file is malformed - end tag names should match start tags, comparison is case-sensitive. Remember to always check whether the document loaded successfully by checking xml_document::load_file return value. As it is right now, the parsing probably fails and you get an empty document (or rather a portion of the document up to the first error, i.e. just the first Object).
2. First loop iterates through children of nodeObjects; for it to work, nodeObjects should refer to Objects tag, not its first Object child.
3. Second and third loops look fine - third loop uses a C++11 feature and as such won't work on compilers that don't support it yet.

Comment: @Ibrahim If zeuxcg's answer was correct, please mark it as such to give him credit. If you consistently give credit for answers, people will be more likely to answer your future questions.